# Symfony Password encryption in an event listener

Tags: symfony-2.1, password-encryption

I am using Symfony 2.1 and the built in security features.

I have set up an entity to store my users:

```
IGA\UserBundle\Entity\SfGuardUser:
  type: entity
  table: sf_guard_user
  id:
    id:
      type: string
      generator: { strategy: UUID }
  fields:
    username:
      type: string
      length: 255
      unique: true
    algorithm:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: true
    salt:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: true
    password:
      type: string
      length: 255
    created_at:
      type: datetime
    last_login:
      type: datetime
      nullable: true
    is_active:
      type: boolean
      default: 1
    is_super_admin:
      type: boolean
      default: 0
  lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [ setCreatedAtValue ]
```

You might recognise the table structure from the old sfGuard plugin in Symfony 1.x. I have legacy databases, so I would like to keep the same table structure going forward.

I know I can encrypt passwords in the controller, but I want the passwords to be encrypted in a prePersist and preUpdate doctrine event so I can limit the encryption logic to one single function.

My event fires just fine, but I need to get the password encryption service from within the doctrine listener. This is my attempt so far:

```
<?php

namespace IGA\UserBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use IGA\UserBundle\Entity\SfGuardUser;

class PasswordEncryptor implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        if ( ($entity instanceof SfGuardUser) && ($entity->needs_encoding) ) {

            $factory = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory');
            $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($entity);
            $entity->setSalt(microtime());
            $encodedPassword = $encoder->encodePassword($password, $entity->getSalt());
            $entity->setPassword($password);

        }
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->preUpdate($args);
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me out with this? Is this a good way of doing things?

It seems the best way to me, because no matter where the entity is updated and stored, the password is encrypted.

If I can only get access to that service!! HELP!!

This will also enable me to use the Sonata Admin Bundle, or any other similar admin generator to manage my users with no additional hassle.